# DokuWiki: Highlight Part in code Block?

Tags: highlight, dokuwiki

I want to highlight/emphasize a part in a code block in dokuwiki.

I could not find a hint in the docs: https://www.dokuwiki.org/wiki:syntax#code_blocks

But maybe I am missing something.

Background: I am not searching for syntax highlighting. I want to emphasize a part.

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible. There are alternative highlight plugins (code2 seems to be popular) that might be able to do that.